# Why is my keyboard loosing it's focus on each taps

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using react native elements input. When ever I type a key in the keyboard it looses it's focus

Below are the version deatils

react-native - 0.59.5
OS           - MAC

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'position' : 'padding'} enabled keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? dimensions.appBarHeight + getStatusBarHeight() + 10 : -100}>
    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        padding: 15,
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 140,
        borderColor: colors.greyLighter,
        borderTopWidth: Platform.OS == 'android' ? 1 : 0,
        shadowOffset: { "width": 0, "height": -3 },
        shadowColor: "black",
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
            <Input
                    inputStyle={{ fontSize: fontSizes.medium }}
                    inputContainerStyle={{
                            position: "relative",
                            padding: 10,
                            marginRight: 30,
                            flex: 1,
                            backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            borderColor: colors.greyLighter,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                    }}
                    multiline
                    placeholderTextColor={colors.greyDarker}
                    placeholder={'Your Comment'}
                    value={commentText}
                    onChangeText={setCommentText}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 32, width: 32, marginLeft: -30 }} onPress={onPostPressed.bind(this, props, navProps.activity)}>
                    <Image
                            style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
                            source={commentText == '' ? require('../../../assets/images/send-disabled.png') : require('../../../assets/images/send.png')}
                    />
            </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

**SetCommentText:**

```
setCommentText: ({ setCommentText }) => text => {
      setCommentText(text);
    }
```

I expect the keyboard should not close whenever I'm pressing a key

Comment: can you post pls the `setCommentText` function too ?

Comment: @oma added what you have asked

Comment: `value={commentText}` Where does it comes from?

Comment: @RishavKumar I'm getting that value from container, commentText will be declared globally in ScreenView